# Unable to get container resource details in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to enable a developer to select an image from an Azure Container Registry when queueing a pipeline. I've followed the website documentation from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#container-resource-variables

My YAML is:

```
resources:         
  containers:
  - container: testContainer
    type: ACR
    azureSubscription: <Subscription>
    endpoint: <EndPoint>
    resourceGroup: <ResourceGroup>
    registry: <Registry>
    repository: <Repository>

stages:
  - stage: DoWork
    jobs:
      - job: DoWork
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo $(resources.container.testContainer.type)
              echo $(resources.container.testContainer.registry)
              echo $(resources.container.testContainer.tag)
```

When I queue the build I can select the image as expected. However, when the pipeline runs it generates errors below.

```
/home/vsts/work/_temp/860b9844-cd34-42b9-8691-060cba8dd11f.sh: line 1: resources.container.testContainer.type: command not found
/home/vsts/work/_temp/860b9844-cd34-42b9-8691-060cba8dd11f.sh: line 2: resources.container.testContainer.registry: command not found
/home/vsts/work/_temp/860b9844-cd34-42b9-8691-060cba8dd11f.sh: line 3: resources.container.testContainer.tag: command not found
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Could you try to add more permissions to Service Principal behind your Service Connection?

Comment: It's currently got contributor permissions. What additional permissions should I try adding?

Comment: Well, this is not clearly stated. But people reported similar problems on developer community problem and in their car the issue was related to service connection and service principal behind.

Answer (score 0):

When you queue the Pipeline and select the image, you can check if you can see the specific version of the docker image.

For example:

[image]

If you are not able to see the version of the image, you can check the following settings:

1.Naviagte to **ACR -> Networking** and check if the ACR has firewall.

If yes, you can refer to the following steps to add Azure DevOps IP to the firewall.

Step1: Check the Azure DevOps organization region in **Organization Settings -> Overview -> Region**.

Step2: Based on the organization region, you can find the related Azure DevOps IP in the doc: [Inbound connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V4#inbound-connections)

For example: **Southeast Asia  -> Asia Pacific  Southeast Asia (Singapore)  20.195.68.0/24**

Step3: Add the Azure DevOps IP to the ACR Firewall.

For example:

[image]

In this case, you will see the docker image version when selecting image resource at queue time.

I tried to use the same YAML sample as yours and it can work as expected.

```
resources:         
  containers:
  - container: testContainer
    type: ACR
    azureSubscription: kevin0905
    endpoint: kevin1017
    resourceGroup: xx
    registry: kevin1005
    repository: test

stages:
  - stage: DoWork
    jobs:
      - job: DoWork
        steps:
          - script: |
              echo $(resources.container.testContainer.type)
              echo $(resources.container.testContainer.registry)
              echo $(resources.container.testContainer.tag)
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I am able to see the images (and their versions) when I am selecting the resource when I queue the build. And we also push and deploy images to the same ACR so I don't think it's a firewall issue. It just doesn't resolve correctly inside the build. Is it possible it is a service connection issue? I saw this issue (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/issue-with-documentation-azure-container-resource/1294278) and so added the endpoint as well - is that needed?

Comment: The endpoint parameter is not necessary in the container resource. You just need to keep using  **azureSubscription** parameter. **Note** The service connection should use Azure Resource Manager Type service connection

Comment: If possible, you can try to create a new ARM service connection with the option: **Service principal (automatic)**. Then you can check if it can work